# java error cannot find symbol when using System.in.read(buffer, 0, 255)

Tags: java, buffer, symbols

My code:

```
public class IOTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("请在下面输入一行字符 ：\n");
    try {
        System.in.read(buffer,0,255);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("读取输入字符出错，错误信息为 ："+e.toString()+"\n");
    }
    System.out.println("您刚才输入的一行字符为 ：\n");
    String inputStr=new String(buffer,0);
    System.out.println(inputStr);
}
}
```

Following is the error information when running the code :

```
D:\dasi\java\javaLab>javac -encoding UTF-8 IOTest.java
`enter code here`IOTest.java:7: 错误: 找不到符号
                    System.in.read(buffer,0,255);
                                   ^


符号:   变量 buffer
  位置: 类 IOTest
IOTest.java:13: 错误: 找不到符号
                String inputStr=new String(buffer,0);
                                           ^
  符号:   变量 buffer
  位置: 类 IOTest
注: IOTest.java使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。
注: 有关详细信息, 请使用 -Xlint:deprecation 重新编译。
2 个错误
```

Can someone help me? I really checked and I still don't know why.
By the way, the Chinese words "错误: 找不到符号" means "error : cannot find symbol".

Comment: What do you think `buffer` is / means?

Comment: Create and initialize buffer.  Better approach to use InputStreamReader

Comment: How to create a buffer

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/126/console-i-o/493/reading-user-input-from-the-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `buffer` variable like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256]
```

Full code:

```
public class IOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("请在下面输入一行字符 ：\n");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; // This line was added
        try {
            System.in.read(buffer,0,255);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("读取输入字符出错，错误信息为 ："+e.toString()+"\n");
        }
        System.out.println("您刚才输入的一行字符为 ：\n");
        String inputStr=new String(buffer,0);
        System.out.println(inputStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on some Java tutorial before proceeding -- such as this one:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

You program has to be changed to something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class IOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("请在下面输入一行字符 ：\n");
        BufferedReader br;
        String inputLine = "";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = br.readLine();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("读取输入字符出错，错误信息为 ："+e.toString()+"\n");
        }
        System.out.println("您刚才输入的一行字符为 ：\n" + inputLine);
        //    String inputStr=new String(buffer,0);
        //    System.out.println(inputStr);
    }
}
```